# How to get the value of id and message separately

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `NSString` response

```
  {"id":"44","message":"1"} ,
```

I want to get the value of

```
"id"
```

and

```
"message"
```

separately. it is the response `NSString` from the server.

Comment: its json string right??not a NSString

Comment: no, it is not json string, it nsstring receiving response from the server like NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];. i get the value from the json string , please also tell me what is difference between json string and nsstring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out.

```
NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary=:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error]];
NSLog(@"id:%@", [dict objectForKey:@"id"]);
NSLog(@"message:%@", [dict objectForKey:@"message"]);
```

It 'll work out.

Comment: i am reciving the value of id like str=(1) but i want only the value str=1. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the response like

```
NSData *data = [stringResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [stringResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//instead of id use NSDictionary
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
NSDictionary *dic=[response JSONValue];
NSDictionary *id=[dic objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString * message =[dic objectForKey:@"message"];
 NSLog(@"id :%@   Message:%@ ",id,message);
```

Good luck!

Comment: i am reciving the value of id like str=(1) but i want only the value str=1. thanks a lot

Comment: NSInteger intID= [id integerValue];
 NSLog(@"id :%d",intID);

Comment: thanks for reply, you did not get my point, i m getting the nsstring value = (1), but i want the only one from the respone not the parenthesis , like =1 , how i can trim the ( and ) from the value, thanks

Comment: exact responseString  of your returns look like?